# multipleForms task

Tags: c#, winforms

```
dsUni = new DataSet();
dsUni.ReadXml(pathDesc);
frm02.dgv02.DataSource = dsUni.Tables[0];
frm02.ShowDialog(); // this all works well
dsUni.WriteXml(pathDesc);  // this is in the frm02ClosingEvent
```

Errors: The names dsUni and pathDesc does not exist in the current context
What should I write and WHERE - to access all the controls and all variables (now and in the future, without any limitations) from frm01 to frm02 and vice versa?

Comment: If they don't exist in the current context can you show us the whole code that has where those 2 variables are declared?

Comment: I cleaned up your question - please keep it civil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `var` in front of dsUni so you have a declaration. pathDesc should contain probably  a path to an XML file, so it must be declared somewhere else. For an introduction to variable scope see http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx or http://www.codecandle.com/Articles/191/Csharp/Variables/Variable-scope/codedetail.aspx